# Android Context Menu appearing on center on Single Click

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm using a Context Menu set on a `LinearLayout` in a `Fragment`. The menu shows up correctly, position relative to the layout on the long click, but on the normal click, the menu appears on center of the screen. How to fix this?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getContext();
        myFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        registerForContextMenu(myFragmentBinding.moreActionsBtn);
        setOnClickListeners();
        rootView = myFragmentBinding.getRoot();
        return rootView;
}

private void setOnClickListeners() {
        myFragmentBinding.moreActionsBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            myFragmentBinding.moreActionsBtn.showContextMenu();
        });
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, view.getId(), 0, "Test Action");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getGroupId() == 0) {
            //todo
        } else {
            return  false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Paste the full code here

Comment: @AliImran I already have provided the code.

Comment: Having the same problem. Is there something obvious that we're missing?